# Firebase Authentication - similar to sessions?

Tags: php, session, firebase, firebase-authentication

For example, I have a web app that allows a user to login and register, once the person has logged in, is it the same as session variables in PHP? Like once I visit other pages of the web app, it still knows that there is someone who has logged in?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/qIQrg8eMdYk

Comment: In some aspects they are similar indeed. But in many other aspects they are very different. Instead of trying to fit a new concept into an existing concept, you'll likely get further by thinking of what use-case you're trying to implement and then see how each tool applies.

Comment: what I want to know if assuming that I logged in to my site then regardless what page i visit I am still logged in to my account (unless of course I logout). the reasons I am asking this is because I've seen tutorials about authentication but they only seem to view about logging in but how about if I visit other pages after I log in

Comment: When a page loads, you can detect whether the user is logged in by listening for the `onAuthStateChanged event. See the [relevant page in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) for an example. I highly recommend that you spend some time in that documentation and maybe even take the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) to familiarize yourself with Firebase.